# SOAP Web Service URL in grails

Tags: grails

I am developing a grails webapp and used SOAP to publish my web service using

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/XYZ", new XYZ());
```

When I am accessing this service from my local machine then it works fine but when I try to access it through different computer using my machine IP address instead of localhost, it does not show anything.

I have allowed the port through firewall as well but still no success.

Can anyone tell me the reason and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default embedded tomcat server will listen on localhost. You will have to explicitely bind it to the ip address.

Try this, and see if works

```
$grails -Dserver.host=192.168.1.100 run-app
```

Or

```
    $grails -Dserver.host=192.168.1.100 run-war
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to solve it. I just need to specify my ip address instead of localhost where I'm publishing my web service.